# Check and mate positions

Tags: chess

Is there a position where your opponent puts you in check, but in your turn you deliver checkmate by getting out of check?

Don't forget to add your list of moves on how to get into the position.

BONUS: Make 2 scenarios where scenario 1 is not a capture, while scenario 2 IS a capture.

If there is such a position, what is the smallest number of moves to get into that position? And, maybe the biggest/smallest amount of points on the board when that happens?

Note: Points work like usual.

Comment: Who downvoted? That kinda hurt my feelings

Comment: This seems to have many different questions involved. It's unclear whether something is actually an answer to your question - this isn't really a puzzle, more many separate questions you have on the topic of chess.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright, I will migrate it

Comment: There are many examples of games where you are put in check but deliver checkmate. Even real games have this happen

Comment: Try chess.stackexchange.com rather than boardgames maybe

Comment: @Laska I'd say it's still to broad for chess.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are even some games like this, such as Hodgeson v Agdestein, London 1986. This example is in Martin Weteschnik's wonderful book [Understanding Chess Tactics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1907982027).

There's some clever tactics going on, but this is the last few moves of the game which ended in this way:

> [image: Hodgeson v Agdestein]